# Stats question on football for uni, need help please? Poisson, lost...

Tags: statistics

need help with Q5 please?

I have added the questions to the web, couldn't pasted the table into this box properly.

www.new-directions.co.uk/mathsquestions.pdf

Much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: ...what is the question?

Comment: Uploaded an image, should be able to view by looking here?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofd7D.jpg